# SQL Server groupby two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table of this structure:

```
   ID   TaskID  ResourceID  IsActive  
  ---   -----   ----------  --------
   1      51        101         1
   2      52        101         1
   3      53        101         1
   4      51        102         0
   5      52        102         0
   6      53        102         0     
   7      51        103         1
   8      52        103         0
   9      53        103         1
```

I want to get the Resources whose `IsActive` column is 0 in all records. In this example I want to get ResourceID- 102 as the result since all it's `IsActive` columns are 0.

I tried doing :

```
select ResourceID
from TableName
where ResourceID <> (SELECT ResourceID
                     from TableName 
                     group by ResourceID, IsActive
                     having IsActive = 1)
```

In the subquery, I'm trying to get all Resources who have IsActive = 1. But when none of the records have IsActive = 1, it returns no result. Hence my main query also fails.  Any suggestions on how to achieve my result?

Edit :

**Solution** :

```
select distinct ResourceID
from TableName t1
where not exists (select 1 from TableName t2
                  where t1.ResourceID = t2.ResourceID
                   and t2.IsActive = 1)
```

Also I think my question is simple and to the point instead of the "possible duplicate" . Future readers might find this question easier to relate to than the suggested duplicate. Users are more likely to search for this problem by "SQL Server groupby two columns" instead of "SQL: Selecting IDs that don't have any rows with a certain value for a column".

Comment: what about `GROUP BY ResourceID HAVING MAX(IsActive) = 0`

Comment: Why not make the sample data more complex, add ResourceID  103, with both 0's and 1's. (And what about null's?)

Comment: @jarlh. You're right . I forgot to add it. Will update it now .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: Selecting IDs that don't have any rows with a certain value for a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261960/sql-selecting-ids-that-dont-have-any-rows-with-a-certain-value-for-a-column)

Comment: @TabAlleman . Kindly read my last edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a row as long as no other row with same ResourceID has IsActive = 1:

```
select ResourceID
from TableName t1
where not exists (select 1 from TableName t2
                  where t1.ResourceID = t2.ResourceID
                   and t2.IsActive = 1)
```

Perhaps you want to do `select distinct ResourceID` to remove duplicates.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ResourceID
FROM
    TableName T
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM TableName
        WHERE
            ResourceID = T.ResourceID AND
            IsActive = 1
    )
```

Or...

```
SELECT ResourceID
FROM
    TableName
GROUP BY
    ResourceID
HAVING
    MAX(IsActive) = 0
```

Comment: No refernce to outer table in the NOT EXISTS sub-select?

Comment: Yep, has just caught it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select ResourceID
from TableName
where ResourceID not in (SELECT ResourceID
                         from TableName 
                         group by ResourceID, IsActive
                         having IsActive = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ResourceID
from TableName 
group by ResourceID 
having max(IsActive) = 0
```